# Static Resources being loaded in different order

Tags: visualforce, jquery, static-resources

I am developing a Salesforce application that is using jQuery, jQueryUI and a custom plugin. The `script` tags in the page markup are in the correct order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="/resource/1384171438000/afdpce__JQuery/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="/resource/1384171438000/afdpce__JQuery/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="/resource/1384170807000/afdpce__IntegrationPlugin"></script>
```

All three are loading (can view the code in Chrome Development Tools), but when inspecting the Network tab they are loading in a different order; the plug-in is loading before the jQueryUi. This means the plugin is failing (there is no widget method).

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Thanks

**Edit**

The goal is to add the scripts to an existing form (i.e. Account Edit) to add functionality.

Currently I have a Visualforce page that is the javascript to dynamically load the js files from static resources, the file paths are using `'{!URLFOR($Resource.name)}'`.

They are being added, just not in the same order. I've found that dynamically added js files ARE added async. So now I'm struggling how to over come this.

Comment: IMO You can not control order of loading of 3 scripts in browser(even if backend is not salesforce).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a visual force problem, resources from a browser are loaded asynchronously, if you have dependencies, try using getScript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577386/loading-required-scripts-into-jquery-plugin

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015251/include-jquery-plugins-with-getscript

Comment: Alternatively, [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), which is also small, and cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

@kevin,

Could you try using 'apex:includescript' instead of using  HTML tag and see how its loading in the network tab?

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.afdpce, 'afdpce__JQuery/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}" />
```

Here i assumed "afdpce" is the Static Resource name of the resource and it is zipped

Comment: adfpce is the namespace, jQuery is the static resource. I've expanded the question (above), I may be approaching the problem the wrong way.

Comment: When you checked your Network Resource in Chrome console, is any one your resource "cached"? I mean cached version would result in faster loading than others. Is the caching set to "PUBLIC" for your resource in Salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin,
can you defer the execution of any JS code in your plugin to after page load?
@Ganesh is right - you can't control the timing of the load process.
Wrote lots of JS/jQuery code - never a problem starting things after page load.